# Check if a number entered by the user with gets.chomp is a float in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have looked for this a long time now and can't find a satisfactory answer. 
I wold like to know how can I check if the number entered by the user is a float. If is a float it is supposed to be an invalid number.

I have something but the result is always true/Integer

Here is what I have so far.

```
puts "What are the first number you want to divide"
number1 = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "What is the second number?"
number2 = gets.chomp.to_i

def is_float(variable)
return variable % 1 == 0
end

if (number1 == 0) && (number2 == 0)
puts "Invalid input"
elsif (is_float(number1) == false) || (is_float(number2) == false)
puts "Invalid input"

else
def divide(number1, number2)
    return number1 / number2
end

    division_result = divide(number1, number2)

def reminder(number1, number2)
    return number1 % number2
end

reminder_results = reminder(number1, number2)
puts ""
puts "Your result is #{division_result}"
puts "Your reminder is #{reminder_results}"
end
```

Comment: If you use `anything.to_i` and do not explicitly convert to a float then any `Math` operation will return an integer.  `3.14159.to_i => 3`

Comment: Have you looked at the definition for [`to_i`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i). `number1` and `number2` are going to be `int`s

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check if the number is an integer, since there are lots of strings the user could enter that aren't floats but are also invalid?

Comment: @JordanRunning Exactly the user input is a `String`. Anything that happens after that is a result of your code decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puts "What are the first number you want to divide"
number1 = gets.chomp.to_i
=> 100
puts "What is the second number?"
number2 = gets.chomp.to_i
=> 3

# Regular math
result_a = number1 / number2
puts "#{number1} / #{number2} = #{result_a}"
=> 100 / 3 = 33 # Integer class persists...

# Use a ruby library instead! Numeric#divmod
result_b = number1.divmod(number2)
puts "Result: #{result_b}"
=> [33, 1] # [quotient, modulus]
```